# Wear app dependency does not resolve to a directory error when creating signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, build, wear-os

I recently reinstalled my windows 10 and now I can't build my signed app (that includes a watch face apk) as I usually can. Android studio now gives me this error. I have tried to put the watch.apk in many directories even on the c: but nothing works. This was never a problem before the reinstall. How can I make this error go away?

[image: error]

Comment: Upon checking your code, you are trying to include an individual file in your dependencies. Have you tried the suggested alternative for [local binary dependency](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#dependency_types)?

Comment: Thanks, I still can't make it work. I think I'll try the recommended method and create a stand alone watchface.